# How to create multiple vertex in SAP HANA Graph

Tags: graph, hana

I'm trying to create 2 (multiple) vertex in SAP HANA like -

Create two table for vertex **ITEM** and **DATASET**

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."ITEM" (
"ITEM_ID" VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
"ITEM_NAME" VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE COLUMN TABLE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."DATASET" (
"DATASET_ID" VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
"DATASET_NAME" VARCHAR(100)
);
```

And creating edge as **REFERENCES**

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."REFERENCES" (
"REF_ID" INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
"SOURCE" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
REFERENCES "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."ITEM" ("ITEM_ID")
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
"TARGET" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
REFERENCES "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."DATASET" ("DATASET_ID")
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
"TYPE" VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Now I would like to connect both vertex (**ITEM** and **DATASET**) with edge  **REFERENCES** like below

```
CREATE GRAPH WORKSPACE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."GRAPH"
EDGE TABLE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."DATASET"
SOURCE COLUMN "SOURCE" 
TARGET COLUMN "TARGET"
VERTEX TABLE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."ITEM" KEY COLUMN "ITEM_ID"
VERTEX TABLE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."DATASET"KEY COLUMN "DATASET_ID"
KEY COLUMN "REF_ID";
```

But it throws this exception at line `VERTEX TABLE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."DATASET"KEY COLUMN "DATASET_ID"`:

> sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "VERTEX": line 6 col 1 (at pos 200)

Is it possible to create multiple vertex in SAP HANA graph ? If yes then what is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding here. The `REFERENCES` clause in the `CREATE TABLE` statement has nothing to do with the graph structure you want to represent.
Instead, it defines a **foreign key constraint** between the two tables.

The `CREATE GRAPH WORKSPACE` command only accepts one `EDGE TABLE` and one `VERTEX TABLE` as parameters.
However, you can also pass in **synonyms** or **views** here.

That way, you could create a view `"ALL_ITEMS"` like this:

```
CREATE VIEW "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."ALL_ITEMS" as
  SELECT "ITEM_ID" as "ID", "ITEM_NAME" as "NAME"  FROM "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."ITEM"
  UNION 
  SELECT "DATASET_ID" as "ID", "DATASET_NAME" as "NAME" FROM "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."DATASET";
```

and then reference this view:

```
CREATE GRAPH WORKSPACE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."GRAPH"
       EDGE TABLE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."DATASET"
            SOURCE COLUMN "SOURCE" 
            TARGET COLUMN "TARGET"
       VERTEX TABLE "GREEK_MYTHOLOGY"."ALL_ITEMS"
            KEY COLUMN "NAME";
```

Using this approach is possible, but you now have to make sure that the `"NAME"` values are unique and not `NULL` across both tables.